# Почему в Java нет виртуальных конструкторов?

Tags: java

Почему в Java нет виртуальных конструкторов, да и вообще - виртуальных статических методов? Идеологические или технические ограничения? В Delphi например есть - весьма удобная вещь.

Comment: Вопрос не совсем по адресу... это вам наверно к разработчикам Явы, которых здесь вы наверно не найдете) Вопрос вам: А зачем? Я как-то без таких вещей обхожусь...
Даже по секрету скажу - я не знаю что это такое и не хочу знать, если я без этого проживу)

Comment: Сразу заметно, что человек перешел с С и еще не освоился. У меня есть знакомый, он сишник. Такой ярый приверженец:) Ни раз с ним холивары разводили.
Ему подсунули проект на java + c++, он поплевался, поругался, понервничал. Потом через год говорит, - "на жава проще" :)
Жду очередного "разочарования" :0

p.s. По теме: я тоже хз что за виртуальный конструктор и у меня есть подозрение: раз он вам надо, значит вы что-то пытаетесь сделать не так :)

Answer (score 2):

В Java для реализации полиморфизма используется позднее связывание. Поэтому все методы по умолчанию виртуальные, кроме static, private, final.

А вообще, что вы подразумеваете под "виртуальным статическим методом"?

Comment: Виртуальный статический метод - значит static и его можно overload в наследнике. Конструктор является в некотором роде тоже статическим методом, но его перегрузка запрещена в Java и C++.


Реализация по идее не должна быть сложной - просто добавить VMT не только к классу, но и к метаклассу, и при вызове статических методов передавать не this (указатель на объект класса), а указатель на объект метакласса. Как это и сделано в Delphi.

Comment: с какого это перепуга перегрузка конструктора в java и с++ запрещена???? и что есть overload? может быть override?

Comment: Тьфу ты блин, конечно, `override`, бьюсь челом о стену.

Answer (score 1):

Как я понимаю, если бы были виртуальные конструкторы (и виртуальные статические методы), мы могли бы писать нечто в этом духе:

```
class A { int m() { return 1; } } 
class B extends A { int m() { return 2; } }
...
Class<A> b = B.class; // так нельзя, но допустим, что можно
A a = b.newInstance();
assert a.m() == 2; // true
```

Таким образом, имея ссылку типа класс А на класс B, мы можем полиморфно сздавать объекты класса B. В Java это достигается абстрактными фабриками. Почему не сделали, как в Delphi (помимо того, конечно, что Delphi это не эталон :))? Возможно, потому что так не сделали в С++ - и такое добавление, на мой взгляд заставило бы существенно пересмотреть объектную модель, сделав ее значительно отличающейся от C++.

Comment: Да, одно из удобных применений виртуальных конструкторов - именно такое.

Delphi конечно не эталон, но несмотря на то что на него все фыркают - не холивара ради - всё-таки весьма удобная вещь, в которой реализованы вещи, отсутсвтующие в майстримных C++ и Java. Навскидку - property, события, finally (нет в C++), виртуальные статические методы, даже лямбды/замыкания есть (в Java пока ещё разрабатываются). В Delphi Prysm есть куча расширений языка (это вообще даже другой язык), например - констрактное программирование (пред- и пост- условия на методы).

Comment: Java вообще очень консерватина (относительно C#, например), один из принципов - это обратная совместимость, так что подобную фичу уже вряд ли добавят, тем более когда она реализуется другими средствами. С другой стороны, JVM подерживает не только Java - Groovy, например, поддерживает метаклассы и, возможно, там такое работает.

Comment: Больше, еще больше, самых разных головоломок.

Comment: property - это не хорошо с точки зрения управления данными. Данные должны быть отдельно, методы отдельно. Странно, что у вас возникают подобные вопросы несмотря на то, что данный язык весьма неплохо обходится без всего этого и более того имеет достаточно обширную историю.

Comment: Имел возможность работать на разных языках, поэтому не привязан ни к какому "лагерю", поэтому адекватно оцениваю достоинства и недостатки различных языков.

property - конечно на вкус и цвет, но на мой - очень удобная вещь для компонентного программирования, в частности - для визуального. И в EJB вроде даже есть неуклюжая имитация свойств, основанная на naming-convenstions.

И в других языкях на JVM виртуальные статические методы не могут быть, т.к. их нет в самой JVM.

А по языкам я вообще присматриваюсь к D - идеальный язык для натива, включает всё лучшее что существует на сегодняшний день.

Comment: Скажу честно, эта фишка в Дельфях мне нравится. Здесь бесспорно. Но с точки зрения правильности я бы отдал предпочтение Java. имхо.

Comment: @codemo http://pastebin.com/gUQNPNTi - это все-таки динамический язык, здесь можно многое из того, что вроде бы нельзя. Аналогично здесь: http://wittykeegan.blogspot.com/2009/10/java-vs-groovy-overriding-static.html